# link MinGW gcc c++ application against mvsc c++ .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mingw

I need to integrate the Intel RealSense C++ library (legacy 2016 R3 not the current 2.0 SDK) to an already existing application built with Qt MinGW g++ 32-bit (installed by Qt5.11 offline installer)

basically, they provide the headers and some .lib files to compile and link applications

when I try to compile the Segmentation example in Visual Studio, they work, (they provide a .props file that I can add to the Visual Studio Solution's Project's Property Manager, btw, I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 Home 64-bit), but, the application I am developing was made using QtCreator so I need to be able to compile with QtCreator, and migrating the build to Visual Studio might not be a viable solution

if I try to compile the Segmentation example with MinGW (32-bit) in QtCreator (installed by Qt5.11 offline installer) I get error messages like this one

```
C:\src\Debug\app\main.cpp:34: error: undefined reference to `UtilCmdLine::UtilCmdLine(Intel::RealSense::Session*, int)'
```

and even if I try to use MSVC (64-bit) in QtCreator (installed by Qt5.11 offline installer) (which is not really a great option)

I get error messages like this one

```
C:\src\Debug\app\main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PXCSession_CreateFromPath referenced in function "public: static class Intel::RealSense::SenseManager * __cdecl Intel::RealSense::SenseManager::CreateInstance(wchar_t const *)" (?CreateInstance@SenseManager@RealSense@Intel@@SAPEAV123@PEB_W@Z)
```

for several symbols

has anyone solved a similar problem?

MinGW I think I understand not working, because of MSVC symbol mangling and a general different ABI, and because the tools to work with .lib files in MinGW are no longer being available (at least not in the official website), but why is MSVC not working? am I missing something that Visual Studio has that QtCreator does not?

would there be a way to make something like a wrapper library in visual studio so that I can use in MinGW? I saw some people who had similar problems with .lib files being told to use a COM style interface if they could

I saw that being the

just to clarify, I'm not sure if it's a problem introduced by the Qt libraries but there is some of the application's code just doesn't compile correctly with MSVC, so for now, I'd prefer a way to compile with MinGW in QtCreator, though we might eventually get it to work with both compilers (or at least try to)

Comment: "they provide the headers and some .lib files to compile and link applications" What exact SDK are you using? Tell us what you downloaded, and what exactly you're doing. There are two choices: [legacy sdk](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/v1.12.1), [current sdk](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense). The C++ SDK (`rs.hpp`) is a header-only library and provides all C++ interfaces, it depends **only** on the C library. So whatever you're doing is fundamentally wrong, and you depend on some other C++ code that is not a part of the SDK (!).

Comment: I am using the 2016 R3 release of the SDK, because the current SDK doesn't have some functionality that was present in the legacy one, and I am certain it is a C++ library (it uses classes), not a C one

I am trying to compile the Segmentation Example

Comment: The C++ "library" is header-only, unless the legacy SDK did something crazy/was designed differently. Alas, it requires signup, so I'm not going to mess with it. You have to figure it out yourself. But it should be easy for you to verify whether it's a header-only C++ library or not. In the modern SDK, all of the C++ header-only library simply forwards the functionality to the C library.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Qt, of course.

Comment: when you say "header only", you mean I don't get to compile the source code? because if that's what you mean, then yes, it is a header-only library, I have to link against the .lib files they provide
the problem with the current SDK is that some functionality is no longer present, and it's the functionality I need